# Issue running PHP query on second machine

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

When I run the following code with mysqli on `machine a` there is no issue executing the query and reviewing the data. However on `machine b`, I receive the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt

I am unsure as to why this would be. Does this error occur on anyone else's machine?

```
<?php 
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = 'ben2';
$dbPass = 'ben';
$dbname = 'test';

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbname);
 if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$firstname = "David";
$lastname = "Peterson";

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO test (fn, ln) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstname, $lastname);
$stmt->execute();   
?>
```

Comment: Try adding `echo mysqli_error($mysqli);` and `var_dump($stmt);` see what other error messages you get and if there's anything in `$stmt` - It could be a bad connection or as the present error message states, an `invalid object` - Googling your error message produced many different possible scenarios.

Comment: thanks, i was able to uncover he real issue by echoin the error

Comment: You're welcome, glad to hear it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)